# Select specific value SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a question, I'm working with sqlite,

first I created a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE tree(
     id_tree integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     id_boss TEXT,
     id_child TEXT,
     answ TEXT);
```

insert some values :

```
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('1','8','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('1',null,'F');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('8','P1','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('8','2','F');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('2','P2','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('2','P3','F');
```

and execute query:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE
 ancestor(id) AS (
  VALUES('P3')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tree.id_boss
  FROM tree JOIN ancestor ON tree.id_child = ancestor.id
  )
 SELECT id FROM ancestor;
```

the result is :

```
  P3
  2
  8
  1
```

My question is, How to make a query to select id_boss that in 'T' value and ignore all that in 'F' ?

The result should be like this :

```
  P3
  1
```

Comment: That result does not show the nodes with `T`.

Comment: `P3` -> `2` , `2` in `F` = ignore, `2` -> `8` , `8` in `F` = ignore, `8` -> `1` , `1` in `T` = show, i think would be like that , am i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter out `F` records from inside the CTE because that would break the connections in the tree.
Instead, you have to return the `answ` values, and use those as a filter in a second step:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
ancestors(id, answ) AS (
  VALUES('P3', 'T')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tree.id_boss, tree.answ
  FROM tree JOIN ancestors ON tree.id_child = ancestors.id
)
SELECT id FROM ancestors WHERE answ = 'T';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

WITH RECURSIVE
 ancestor(id) AS (
  VALUES('P3')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tree.id_boss
  FROM tree JOIN ancestor ON tree.id_child = ancestor.id and tree. answ='F'
  )
 SELECT id FROM ancestor;

Comment: thanks for answer, but it's not work , the result is show `2` and `8`